# Как сделать обновление DataGrid без сброса фокуса? (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Здравствуйте! У меня имеется DataGrid где часто обновляются данные. Постоянно приходит список с похожими данными, только некоторые ячейки меняются. Но дело в том, что при каждом обновлении DataGrid'а сбрасывается фокус с ячейки. Также когда жмешь на кнопку в DataGrid и в этот момент происходит обновление датагрида, то клик по кнопке не проходит. Каким способом можно обновить DataGrid так, чтобы при этом ячейки, которые не потерпели изменения не сбрасывали с себя фокус? Т.е. фактически не обновлялись?

Comment: А как вы обновляете? Если у вас идет привязка с INPC и реализован грамотно MVVM, то выделение пропадать не должно. Если вы запихиваете элементы в DataGrid повторно, то там уже да, все сбросится.

Comment: Ну я просто меняю ItemsSource на новый. Другим способом не знаю как обновлять. У меня данные с сокета приходят

Comment: Научитесь делать привязку (Binding) и тогда пропадут данные трудности. Ну либо перед заменой ItemsSource сохраняйте id выделенного элемента, а после устанавливайте (но это по сути "костыль", как и ваше переназначение ItemSource)

Comment: А как сделать с помощью биндинга, если у меня данные из сокета приходят? Т.е. постоянно новая коллекция

Comment: Ну смотрите.. У Вас одна коллекция постоянно привязана к нужным элементам. Вы ее не в коем случае не отвязываете, а лишь работаете с ее содержимом. В вашем случае - либо полностью очищаете старые элементы (что приведет скорей всего к сбросу), либо ищите в новых данных из сокета отличия и только их переносите в привязанную коллекцию

Comment: Походу только искать данные которые отличаются и обновлять их

Comment: Пытаюсь сделать с помощью биндинга, все равно сбрасывет фокус, странно....

Comment: Показывайте пример того, как пытаетесь сделать